# Delete middle element of a stack in js

Tags: javascript, data-structures, stack, logic

I have wanted to get the middle elements of a stack, so I have created a function deleteMid and recursively called the remove function to check and pop the middle elements, but here I am getting an output of undefined, so how can you please rectify that code? code is given below.

```
   function deleteMid(s, sizeOfs) {
        let count = 0;
        let mid = Math.floor(sizeOfs / 2);
        remove(s, count, mid, sizeOfs);
    }

    function remove(s, count, mid, sizeOfs) {
        if (count === mid) {
            s.pop();
            return;
        }

        let num = s.pop();
        remove(s, count + 1, mid, sizeOfs);
        s.push(num);
    }
    console.log(deleteMid([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 5))
```

Comment: have you heard of `Array#splice` method? and `Array#length` property?

Comment: yes array.splice method

Comment: seems to be perfect for what you want, doesn't it? `function deleteMid(s) { s.splice(s.length>>1, 1); }`

Comment: I am not able to do that in return [3]. What about the rest of the code? I want to return [1, 2, 4, 5].

Comment: what? what do you mean? your `deleteMid` function didn't return anything, so neither does the suggestion

Comment: can you pls modify that programme with a optimize solution ?

Comment: modify what? yours? I did, with that single line. It does what your code is attempting (and failing) to do, remove the middle element of an Array -

Comment: it returns the deleted elements but i want to return the rest elements apart from deleting elements

Comment: no it doesn't - it doesn't return anything, just like your `deleteMid` function returns nothing ... did you wish to **return** something from `deleteMid`? then `return s` as the next line of the function - or even something like `const deleteMid=s=>(s.splice(s.length>>1,1),s);`

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine, except that you should not output the value *returned* by `deleteMid`, but instead should keep a reference to the stack that you have passed as argument to it. So change in the main program the following line:

```
console.log(deleteMid([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 5));
```

to:

```
const stack = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; // Keep a reference to the stack
deleteMid(stack, stack.length);
console.log(stack); // Output the mutated stack
```

Now the output will be:

```
[1, 2, 4, 5]
```

#### Remarks

Not your question, but:

- It is a pity you have to provide the length of the stack as a separate argument, and that after the deletion you don't get an adapted size back from the function. Arrays have a `length` property, so you could just use that. If this is an assignment where you are not allowed to use the `length` property, then create a `Stack` class that maintains a `size` property.
- Your `remove` function has too many parameters. It doesn't need `sizeOfs`: it never uses it other than passing it along to recursive calls.
- Instead of using the `count` argument -- which increases -- you could pass `mid-1` to recursive calls. This saves another parameter.
- For integer division by 2, it is more elegant to use the `>>` operator instead of `Math.floor`.
- Arrays have a `splice` method which does the job. But I suppose this is an assignment, where you were asked not to use any Array method other than `push` and `pop`.
- The variable name `s` would suggest it is a string. Instead use a more descriptive name, like `stack`.
- Your `remove` method has two places where it calls `pop`. This could be done in just one place, moving the early exit right after it.

Here is your code with some of the above comments taken into account:

```js
function deleteMid(stack, stackSize) {
    // Use bitshift to integer-divide by 2.
    // Don't pass count, nor sizeOfs as argument
    remove(stack, stackSize >> 1); 
}

function remove(stack, indexFromTop) {
    const value = stack.pop();
    if (indexFromTop == 0) { // Base case exit moved after the pop call. 
        return;
    }
    remove(stack, indexFromTop - 1);
    stack.push(value);
}

const stack = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
deleteMid(stack, 5);
console.log(stack);
```

To make the changed stack size available to the caller, and to prevent the caller from using any other array properties than `push` and `pop`, you could define a `Stack` class, like so:

```js
/* Define a class so that you can enforce that no Array properties other than
 * push and pop can be used, and that you can maintain a size that is also 
 * available after deleting elements
 */ 
class Stack { 
    #stack; // Private array property so caller cannot access it nor its methods
    
    constructor(...values) {
        this.#stack = values;
    }
    // Only expose the stack-related methods
    get length() {
        return this.#stack.length;
    }
    push(value) {
        this.#stack.push(value);
    }
    pop() {
        return this.#stack.pop();
    }
    // Custom methods:
    deleteMid() {
        // Use bitshift to integer-divide by 2.
        // Don't pass count, nor sizeOfs as argument
        this.remove(this.length >> 1); 
    }
    remove(indexFromTop) {
        const value = this.pop();
        if (indexFromTop == 0) { // Base case exit moved after the pop call. 
            return;
        }
        this.remove(indexFromTop - 1);
        this.push(value);
    }
    // To help printing the stack (or for other purposes), 
    //    make the stack iterable
    *[Symbol.iterator]() {
        yield* this.#stack;
    }
}

const stack = new Stack(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
stack.deleteMid();
console.log(...stack); // Use iterator to print the stack's values
```